# undefined reference to `QSound::play(QString const&)'

Tags: qt, audio, ubuntu, qt5

Trying to play sound, via QSound (QT 5, Ubuntu 13.04)

The code:

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QSound>
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
QSound::play("sounds/win.wav");
}
```

And getting 2 errors:
undefined reference to `QSound::play(QString const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What am i doing wrong ? In [documentation here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html) i see the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the multimedia module. Add this to your .pro file:

```
QT += multimedia
```